# Missing PACMAN command, can I install it without connecting internet?

Tags: setup, software-installation, packages

I would like to set up ADSL connection for my RPi
I've download ppp and rp-pppoe (pkg.tar.xz) and want to use pacman command to install the packages
But in my RPi system can not find pacman tool
My RPi system image is Raspbian
Is there another way to set up ADSL connection without internet connect?

Comment: I found the answer, I should use *.deb with dpkg tool to install application (I can not post answer for my question in 8 hours due to I am a newbie, I am sorry if this question waste your time)

Comment: No problem Ronald. We all understand, as we have all been there. :) Like @Lawrence said, Raspbian doesn't use the `pac-man` command, it uses the `apt-get` for its package manager, so you don't need to install PAC-MAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.
For Raspbian, you should be using `apt-get install <package name>`
apt-get is the package manager for Raspbian, much like how pacman is the package manager for Arch Linux